# Sorting items into batches

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on an Excel VBA-based calculator to help plan shipping of steel plates, and part of what I've been asked to do is organize the plates into a minimum number similarly-sized stacks based on certain tolerances and the maximum stacking height.

Problem is, I have no idea how to do it, or if it's even possible. I assume it'll have to start by sorting the plates by width and length (haven't been told yet which is to be prioritised), then evaluating which ones can be combined to form as few stacks as possible (while keeping width differences below 15% and stack heights below 2.5m). I just don't know how to actually make it *do* it...

Any suggestions?

---

*Edit to avoid lengthy comment to-and-fro:*

We get cargo lists of metal plates, where each line item has a quantity, length, width, height and weight. We also have rolltrailers (RT) of set dimensions, with a maximum capacity (allowing for overhangs) defined by width, length and weight for each size of rolltrailer. The ships they're to be loaded on, along with steel packing procedures, limit the maximum height for all stacks to 2.5m.

The size of rolltrailer is selected based on the length of the longest plate in the stack. The order of the plates within the stacks is not important - that's operational, so not something the calculator I'm building needs to do. Within each stack, the narrowest plate has to be no less than 85% the width of the widest plate. Mixed stacks, as long as the width variance within each stack is within that 15% window, can be stacked on top of each other as long as the total height and weight are within the limits mentioned above.

The workflow as it stands in the current draft is as follows: - Identify longest plate --> Select RT - IF total height of item 1 < 2.5m, stack the next item that will fit - UNTIL total height OR total weight => max height/weight - Calculate remaining line items - Return to start until all line items are stacked Now off to do some googling.

The plates don't have consistent densities, unfortunately - sometimes it's mild steel, sometimes carbon steel, sometimes other metals entirely. :-(

@John Coleman:

> Is there an upper bound on RTs of various sizes? Also -- do longer RTs in some sense cost more than shorter ones, so that a solution with more but shorter RTs might be preferred to a solution with fewer but longer?

The largest RT is 24.4 m long and can take cargo with a maximum length of 26.0 m. Pricing calculations are based on the footprint, and the smallest category of RT (6.1 m) has a slightly lower cost per square metre than the other categories. In general, though, usual practice has been to use 12.2 m RTs for steel cargos for possible because of their abundance and simplicity of loading.

---

**Dimension limits**
There are different overhang limits for different trailers; the forkliftable bolsters can have an overhang of two metres either end, but only 0.25m either side. The longer trailers, by contrast, have more limited overhangs in length but up to half a metre either side. I'm thinking of just putting the maximum dimensions in the lookup table to avoid having to think about it too much.

**Sample cargo**
A selection of random cargo

```
Ln Itm  Cargo Description   Type    Qty L (m)   W (m)   H (m)   Weight (kg)
3       Steel Plate         Plates  1    6.000  3.000   0.025    3,533.000
4       Steel Plate         Plates  1    4.000  2.580   0.150   12,152.000
16      Steel plates        Plates  60   2.000  1.000   0.080    1,256.000
```

Comment: If your objective is to minimize the number of stacks then it sounds like a variation of the bin-packing problem. You should be able to formulate it as an integer-programming problem, in which case Excel's solver can handle it -- as long as the number of integer variables is not too large. Alternatively, you could take some of the known heuristics for bin-packing and modify them to apply to your scenario. If you state the problem requirements more precisely, I might be able to come up with a mathematical formulation of it.

Comment: (I'll spec out the problem for now, then wander off and google bin-packing...) :-D  
  
We get cargo lists of metal plates, where each **line item** has a **quantity**, **length**, **width**, **height** and **weight**.  
  
We also have rolltrailers (RT) of set dimensions, with a maximum capacity (allowing for overhangs) defined by **width**, **length** and **weight** for each size of rolltrailer. The ships they're to be loaded on, along with steel packing procedures, limit the maximum height for all stacks to **2.5m**.

Comment: The size of rolltrailer is selected based on the length of the longest plate in the stack.

The order of the plates within the stacks is not important - that's operational, so not something the calculator I'm building needs to do.

Within each stack, the narrowest plate has to be no less than **85%** the width of the widest plate.

Mixed stacks, as long as the width variance within each stack is within that 15% window, can be stacked on top of each other as long as the total height and weight are within the limits mentioned above.

Comment: The workflow as it stands in the current draft is as follows:  
  
- Identify longest plate --> Select RT  
- IF total height of item 1 < 2.5m, stack the next item that will fit  
- UNTIL total height OR total weight => max height/weight  
- Calculate remaining line items  
- Return to start until all line items are stacked  
  
Now off to do some googling. Thanks!

Comment: They don't, unfortunately - sometimes it's mild steel, sometimes carbon steel, sometimes other metals entirely. :-(

Comment: The largest RT is 24.4 m long and can take cargo with a maximum length of 26.0 m. Pricing calculations are based on the footprint, and the smallest category of RT (6.1 m) has a slightly lower cost per square metre than the other categories. In general, though, usual practice has been to use 12.2 m RTs for steel cargos for possible because of their abundance and simplicity of loading.

Comment: (Having seen the bit where it says "please avoid extended discussions in comments" and subsequently read the FAQs, I've incorporated that extra information into the question.)

Comment: Any thoughts? I've got a few ideas to just sort the plates by width and then stack up to max height, but I'm not sure how well optimized the stacks would be then.

Comment: Sorry -- I am in the middle of finals week right now. What you described as your current practice earlier does seem like a first-fit decreasing heuristic for bin-packing. Some sort of evolutionary algorithm might be appropriate. It might help if you post some mocked-up sample data and gave a listing of possible RT dimensions. Am I correct in assuming that the plates can overhang each other (within the 15% limit) but can't overhang the RTs?

Comment: They can overhang the trailers - set maximum lengths based on the trailer length, and unspecified overhangs in width. The limit is, as far as I can tell, "no limit as long as the plate doesn't flex too much". I'll put some sample data in the original post so I can structure it a bit. Thanks!